# Issue with grease pencil and where lines meet

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d

I have a recurring problem where I can't make the lines of the grease pencil meet without the ends being rounded. I'll use this circle and line as an example to what I'm referring to.

[image]

[image]

[image]

It appears that I'm only able to erase lines in linear segments rather than the specific part that I want to get rid of. I understand that the grease pencil doesn't really use pixels which is what I'm used to when working with other art softwares.

Is there an easy fix to this?

Comment: You could either go into edit mode and move the endpoints so that the rounded part completely overlaps the other line (perhaps using proportional editing with "Connected only" enabled), or for this specific case you could try taking a look at [masking](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/properties/masks.html).

Comment: I'll look into this. Thank you